# (c++) Going through an array in 4 different ways with the same code

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm doing some computations on a 2D array and need to go through the array in 4 different ways

```
for(int i=0; i < array_size; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j < array_size; j++) {
      #do some computation around [i][j] element
   }
}

for(int i = array_size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   for(int j=0; j < array_size; j++) {
      #do the same computation around [i][j] element
   }
}


for(int i=0; i < array_size; i++) {
   for(int j=array_size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      #do the same computation around [i][j] element
   }
}



for(int i = array_size - 1; i >=0; i--) {
   for(int j = array_size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      #do the same computation around [i][j] element
   }
}
```

The thing is that, first, the code for the computation is long and also might be changed in the future. And second, the arrays are huge, so the performance is also an issue here.

I've been wondering if there is any way how to avoid code duplication and preserve the performance. Since the extraction of the code into a function would probably decrease the performance.

Comment: "the extraction of the code into a function would probably decrease the performance", first: that's what `inline` is for. second: compilers are pretty smart these days, don't optimize prematurely and don't optimize without timing it first

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  There's a gadget in programming languages called 'functions'.  It sounds like the body of your loop needs to be a function which takes the `array[i][j]` element as one of its parameters.  The chances of it seriously reducing the performance are limited.  You'd have to demonstrate it.  The more complex the code, the less likely it is that extraction into a function will hurt performance.

Comment: Do the computations have to be done in that order? If not, you can just collapse them into one set of for loops. Also, unless there's any kind of optimization with the computations themselves, you aren't gonna get better performance than O(m*n)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler he's obviously aware of functions, but refuses to use them because he is afraid of performance decrease

Comment: Yeah, and I just qualified my comment...

Comment: Most of commenters are missing this: `around [i][j] element`. The order does matter.

Comment: Basically the 1st and 4th can be combined into one, And the 2nd and 3rd into one set. Each of them produce the sequence in reverse order.

Comment: Agree with sharth'a answer. Verify in Release Asssembly code that function is really inlined. If not - use macro. Or even `#include` the code fragment. When performance is important, we need to forget many programming style rules.

Comment: I assume your 2D array is a square matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an inline function, it's likely that your compiler will do the inlining for you, thus giving you the result that you want.

```
inline void work(int i, int j) { ... }
```

---

If you wanted to be more scientific about this, and this function takes a non-trivial amount of time, then I would recommend investing in a profiler. On the open source side, some people would recommend [gprof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof). On the proprietary side, some people (including myself) would recommend [Intel's VTune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTune).

Comment: Note that if `work` is long, simply giving `inline` as above may not inline the call. The compiler will decide if inlining is appropriate. For gcc, you could try `inline void work(...) __attribute__((always_inline));`

Comment: @JoshG79 If `work` is long, it's unlikely that the function call overhead is a problem.